npm warnings when using npm install using Vite
I am new to using Vite and I am running into these warnings when trying to scaffold my project.
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
added 278 packages, and audited 279 packages in 29s
103 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
Additionally, I can't see the vite icon and instead just see js icon on VSCode and I don't know how to solve it. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/vTpeZpYo.png)
I have tried using npm install inflight@latest rimraf@latest glob@latest and am still running into the same problems.
my node and npm versions are v20.14.0 and 10.7.0 respectively
I have also used npm update but to no avail.
